# Salesforce FullForce Solution

Tags: community, certification, partner, criteria, solutions

Do you by any chance know what are the criteria that are taken in consideration to certify a Salesforce FullForce Solution? And what are the steps that should be followed in certifying a Salesforce FullForce Solution?

I was searching online, but nothing specific regarding the criteria or the steps, fullforce it only said to "*reach out to your Partner Account Manager.*"

Comment: You might be interested in the [FullForce Trailmix](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/jamesspringer/trailmixes/the-complete-lightning-dev-monster-trail), but aside from that, I don't think there's much publicly available information, so contacting your Partner Account Manager would probably be ideal.

Comment: Thank you for the link to FullForce Trailmix, I went thru it a bit but I don't think is related to what I need.